# Connecting external screen to BQ aquaris e4.5 ubuntu edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, display, phone, aquaris, bq

I want to buy a BQ Aquaris E4.5, but i want to try convergence with this phone. My question is: how can i connect it to a external monitor? Does Miracast, or other wireless display technologies, work with this device? Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug report with the response that the feature won't be brought to Aquaris 4.5

https://bugs.launchpad.net/aethercast/+bug/1598559

If you need it as well you can vote for the bug.

Answer (score 0):

you can try miracast by trying the following commands
`aethercastctl`
`enable`

aethercastctl will drop you in a shell where you can use aethercast(miracast) using commands. you can get a list of all available commands by typing "help"